# CodeIgniter URL Query String Manipulation

Tags: php, codeigniter, post, get, query-string

I have a E-Commerce Website build using CodeIgniter 2.3.

Please suggest how can I manipulate the URLs in the given sequence:-

1. Say a Person Searches for "Mobile Phones". 
   **URL must be xyz.com/search/mobile-phone**, which displays all the Mobile Phones from our Database.
   *I am already aware of the Search controller and use Routing to exclude the function name from the URL*
2. Next the Person uses filtering by name of Mobile Phone Companies. Suppose he chooses "Apple". The **URL must become xyz.com/search/mobile-phones/apple**
3. Next the Person again filters by Condition ie "New" or "Refurbished". The **URL must become xyz.com/search/mobile-phones/apples/new**
4. The URLs need to be Functional URLs so that, if I pass the URL xyz.com/search/mobile-phones/apples/new to someone externally, he/she should be able to see the same result set as the person who came after Search & Filtering.

I am non-technical so may be I couldnt explain my problem very technically, but be assured, my Tech Person would be reading your suggestions.

**Further Details**

We are already using URI Segmentation, Routing & Post Method. But that way we are facing issues wrt Point #4 mentioned above

Comment: You can use CodeIgniter routing to solve this issue. Please ask your tech person to look into it.

Comment: You can use the routes.php in the application/config/routes.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use a controller like this suppose your controller file name is Search.php

add this route to config/route.php to this
`$route['search/(.+)']='search/index/$1';`

then in your search php specify index function

```
function index($search_type,$brand=null,$category=null){
    //write something here
}
```

so when you access 
xyz.com/search/mobile-phones/apple
The route will redirect this too xyz.com/search/index/mobile-phones/apple
The mobile-phones will be stored to `$search_type` and apple will be stored to `$brand`.

if you search xyz.com/search/mobile-phones/apple/new
The route will redirect this too 
xyz.com/search/index/mobile-phones/apple
The mobile-phones will be stored to `$search_type`,
apple will be stored to `$brand`,
and new will be passed to `$category`.

References on routing
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

References on Controller parameter passing 
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#passing-uri-segments-to-your-methods

Answer (score 0):

You can do these stuff by give route to every method call of your controller 
methods like this -:

For example your controller is
Mobile.php

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Mobile extends CI_Controller {
public function getMobiles()
{
    $uri_3 = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $uri_4 = $this->uri->segment(4);

    if($uri_3 !="" &&  $uri_4 =="" ){
        //make search by mobile brand ,like apple
        echo $uri_3;die;
    }else if($uri_3 !="" & $uri_4 !=""){
        echo $uri_3.'-'.$uri_4; die;
        //make search by brand and new , like apple/new
    }else{
        //make search for all mobile brand by default
        echo 'All';die;
    }
  }
}
```

and the route.php file should be like this-:

```
$route['search/mobile-phone'] = 'Mobile/getMobiles';
$route['search/mobile-phone/(:any)'] = 'Mobile/getMobiles';
$route['search/mobile-phone/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'Mobile/getMobiles';
```

Url should be like this -:

```
http://localhost:90/ci_test/index.php/search/mobile-phone/apple/new
```

if you are not using index.php in url then your uri segments would be change so be care full for that

```
http://localhost:90/ci_test/index.php/search/mobile-phone/apple/new
O/P- apple-new

http://localhost:90/ci_test/index.php/search/mobile-phone/apple/
O/P- apple

http://localhost:90/ci_test/index.php/search/mobile-phone/
O/P- All
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to do this answer with script, from client side.

**1. Say a Person Searches for "Mobile Phones". URL must be xyz.com/search/mobile-phone, which displays all the Mobile Phones from our Database. I am already aware of the Search controller and use Routing to exclude the function name from the URL**

simply get the input value and pass it to script.

```
<script>

$('#search').keyup(function (e) {

if(e.keyCode==13)
{
    var search=$('#search').val();

    window.location.href = 'xyz.com/search/'+search;
}
});

</script>
```

**2. Next the Person uses filtering by name of Mobile Phone Companies. Suppose he chooses "Apple". The URL must become xyz.com/search/mobile-phones/apple**

when the person clicks apple, you are going to write.

`onclick="javascript:window.location.href='xyz.com/search/<?php echo $this->uri->segment(3).'/Apple'; ?>';"`

**3. Next the Person again filters by Condition ie "New" or "Refurbished". The URL must become xyz.com/search/mobile-phones/apples/new**

assuming selection box for new or refurbished.

```
$('#select').change(function(e) { 

        var select=$('#select').val();

        window.location.href = 'xyz.com/search/<?php echo $this->uri->segment(3)."/".$this->uri->segment(4); ?>'+select;

 });
```

**4. The URLs need to be Functional URLs so that, if I pass the URL xyz.com/search/mobile-phones/apples/new to someone externally, he/she should be able to see the same result set as the person who came after Search & Filtering.**

and in controller, you can get the values with the uri segment.

```
$this->uri->segment(3)
$this->uri->segment(4)
$this->uri->segment(5)
```

and make the query a your wish and return the result.

the above url works for all, if you make the query result with the parameters.

i have not write any validation, so make the validations and pass it to the url whether user input is empty or not.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

For ex:
   Your URL is :  xyz.com/search/mobile-phones/apple/condition/new

```
 $segment_array=$this->uri->segment_array();
 $mobile_brand=array_search('mobile-phones',$segment_array);    
        if($mobile_brand !==FALSE && $this->uri->segment($mobile_brand+1)!='')
        {
            $mobile_brand = $this->uri->segment($mobile_brand+1); //apple
        }

 $condition=array_search('condition',$segment_array);   
        if($condition !==FALSE && $this->uri->segment($condition+1)!='')
        {
            $condition = $this->uri->segment($condition+1); //new
        }
```

You can follow up your coding by checking $mobile-brand & $condition to restrict the result.
This way it will not conflict other parameters, passing parameters with key and value approach.

Try and let me know you output.